# Should we declare and check null or use isset in PHP?

Tags: php

Which approach is considered best practice?

Declare and check null...

```
class Foo {
  $bar = null;
  function test() {
    return $this->bar != null;
  }
}
```

Or, `isset(...)`...

```
class Foo {
  function test() {
    return isset($this->bar);
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use either, just for readability I would use `return !is_null($this->bar);`

Comment: Use return !empty($this->bar);

Comment: I would suggest !empty() because it will check both isset and null conditions.

Comment: what about `return $this->bar !== null`?

Comment: Declaring and setting as null can probably make your code more readable rather than have others trying to figure out where $bar is coming from.

Comment: If `$bar` is a (logical) property of your object, car -> model for instance, then it makes sense to create that property and check whether it has data set to it. However, if it's a *magic* class member being set through `__set()` then check with `isset()`

Comment: First is more programmaticall

Comment: @Indrajit `isset` will check for both isset and `null` conditions...! `empty` does not check for just `null`.

Comment: @deceze empty checks for null,'',0,false you can see its definition in php.net

Comment: @Indrajit I am [very aware](http://kunststube.net/isset) what `empty` does. And I'm saying for the purpose of "isset and `null` check", all you need is `isset`. Checking for all these other values as well is possibly not desired here.

Answer (score 3):

It makes a lot more sense to declare all the properties your class has, and check what their values are. It gives you a clear sense of what the class can do and what values it may have, rather than guessing every step of the way what property some other function may be looking for sometime later.

```
class Foo {
  protected $bar = null;
  public function test() {
    return $this->bar !== null;
  }
}
```

Note the `!==` check here; if you'd just use `!=` the condition would be true for a number of other values besides just `null`.

It really is the exact same thing as any other variables in your code: you should always initialise any and all variables your code will work with, and then just worry about their values. `isset` should be used exclusively for cases where you have **no control** over the existence of a variable, e.g. as is the case for user input. For any other situation where you have perfect control over the existence or non-existence of your variable, opt for explicitly initialising them.